# Why does Connect-PnPOnline - interactive prompt me to grant seemingly ALL permissions (in the context of implementing Sites.Selected)?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am trying to implement `Sites.Selected` functionality.

This is for the purpose of granting an application access to a specific SharePoint Site (not all of them).

The process seems to consist of three parts:

1. Register an application in Azure AD
2. Grant the application `Sites.Selected` permissions in Microsoft Graph API (Application)
3. Run one of the following commands to specify which sites the app should have access to:

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Set-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission.html

Using a script such as:

```bash
# This is the Name of the Azure app registration  
$appDisplayName = "MyAppRegistrationName"  

# This is Application Client ID of the Azure app registration named MyAppRegistrationName
$appId = "********"  

# This is the URL of the site to be accessed  
$siteCollUrl = "https://*******.sharepoint.com/sites/*******"  

write-host "Connecting to your site."  

# This prompts for login in the browser (365 Admin uses their admin account to login)  
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteCollUrl -Interactive -ReturnConnection
if (-not $connection) {
    write-host "Failed to connect to the site." -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
}

write-host "Granting app $appDisplayName access"  

# This grants the app registration Write permission to the site collection    
$grantResult = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions "Write" -Site $siteCollUrl -AppId $appId -DisplayName $appDisplayName
if (-not $grantResult) {
    write-host "Failed to grant permissions." -ForegroundColor Red
    exit
}

write-host "Permissions granted successfully." -ForegroundColor Green
```

I have completed steps 1 and 2,

However, when I attempt to run `Connect-PnPOnline`, it opens a browser where I login using my 365 admin account, and it then prompts me to consent to granting what seems to be every high level permission that exists (47 of them).

I then click 'Cancel' because I don't understand what is happening.

==========

This application is not published by Microsoft or your organization.

This app would like to:

Read and write Records Management configuration, labels, and policies

Read and write all external connections

Update your user status on service announcement messages

Read all company places

Read user sensitivity labels and label policies.

Read your chat messages

Read and write your chat messages

Read your organization's policies

Read and write to all app catalogs

Read audit log data

Read your organization’s security events

Read all OneNote notebooks that you can access

Invite guest users to the organization

Read all usage reports

Read mail you can access

Read and write all groups

Read and write directory data

Access the directory as you

Read and write access to your mail

Send mail as you

Read your calendars

Read and write identity providers

Read bookings information

Read your online meetings

Send channel messages

Read and write tabs in Microsoft Teams.

Read and write the names, descriptions, and settings of channels

Read and change teams' settings

Add and remove members from teams and channels

Add and remove members from teams and channels

Read your channel messages

Manage your installed Teams apps

Create teams

Read service messages

Read service health

Create, read, update, and delete your tasks and task lists

Read all transcripts of online meetings.

Access the PowerApps Service API

Access Common Data Service as you

View all datasets

Read activity data for your organization

Read service health information for your organization

Read and write managed metadata

Have full control of all site collections

Read and write user profiles

Access the directory as you

Access Azure Service Management as you

==========

It also has a checkbox that says:

==========

"Consent on behalf of your organisation"

And beneath that a message:

"Accepting these permissions means that you allow this app to use your data as specified in their terms of service and privacy statement. The publisher has not provided links to their terms for you to review. You can change these permissions at https://myapps.microsoft.com.  Show details

Does this app look suspicious? Report it here"

==========

**Question:**

I am confused why the command `Connect-PnPOnline` is asking me to consent to all of these permissions.

The ONLY permissions that the application registration has in the `API Permissions` section in Azure are:

- Microsoft Graph (2)
  -- Application, Sites.Selected
  -- Delegated, User.Read (this was here by default after I registered the application)

And `Admin consent` was granted in this area as well.

And the ONLY permission that is defined in the PowerShell script is:

```bash
$grantResult = Grant-PnPAzureADAppSitePermission -Permissions "Write" -Site $siteCollUrl -AppId $appId -DisplayName $appDisplayName
```

I've read these associated articles, but they don't seem to shed any light on my situation:

https://github.com/pnp/powershell/discussions/1693

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/controlling-app-access-on-specific-sharepoint-site-collections/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-sharepoint-blog/develop-applications-that-use-sites-selected-permissions-for-spo/ba-p/3790476

https://www.extendm365.com/2022/04/how-to-give-app-access-on-specific.html

https://pankajsurti.com/2021/12/15/how-do-sites-selected-work-for-granular-permissions-for-spo-sites/

https://ashiqf.com/2021/03/15/how-to-use-microsoft-graph-sharepoint-sites-selected-application-permission-in-a-azure-ad-application-for-more-granular-control/

https://www.leonarmston.com/2022/01/pnp-powershell-csom-now-works-with-sharepoint-sites-selected-permission-using-azure-ad-app/

https://www.agrenpoint.com/pnp-powershell-consent-and-authentication/

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Connect-PnPOnline.html